# Connecting iPhone 4 to MacBook Pro via Bluetooth

Tags: macos, iphone, bluetooth, macbook-pro

I'm having issues when trying to connect my new MacBook Pro to my iPhone 4 via Bluetooth. I'm trying to connect my iPhone to my MacBook so that I can use the iPhone as a hotspot through Bluetooth and not wi-fi or a cable.

Things I've done:
I start off by clicking the Bluetooth icon, then go to "Set Up Bluetooth Device..."
I then select my iPhone when it appears. The pairing popup comes up on my iPhone but it never does pair... I get a popup on my phone later on stating the MacBook Pro was not compatible.

What can be done to troubleshoot tethering over bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/48621/28877) by @DanielSchlaug on the same subject: It certainly helped me (and a few other people).

Here's the content of Daniel's the answer:

> This fixes what i presume to be a corrupt internet sharing preference file. It will also remove all other network settings such as wifi access-points and their passwords so keep that in mind. Other data such as pictures and contacts will be completely safe.
>
> 1. On your iPhone, go to `Settings -> General -> Reset` and choose `Reset Network Settings`.
> 2. The iPhone will ask you to confirm and then restart.
> 3. In `Settings -> Internet Sharing` reenable it and choose to turn on bluetooth if a dialog asking to do so appears.
> 4. Reconnect to your wifi-network if applicable.
> 5. **You're probably done**, try connecting. If it doesn't work go on.
> 6. In `Settings -> General -> Bluetooth` tap the blue arrow beside your computer and choose to forget the device.
> 7. On your computer go to `System Preferences -> Bluetooth` and remove your iPhone from the list.
> 8. Go to `System Preferences -> Network`. In the Location drop down choose `Edit Locations...`. Add a new location and press done.
> 9. Make sure the new location is selected and press `Apply`.
> 10. Go back to `System Preferences -> Bluetooth` and re-pair your phone to the computer.
> 11. Connect to your iPhone's bluetooth network.
> 12. Back in `System Preferences -> Network` if you do not have a `Bluetooth PAN` interface add it by pressing the `+` button in the lower left.
> 13. Press `Apply` and cross your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me (Iphone 4 BT connected with MacBook Air 13 2012):

1. Turn ON iPhone's Personal Hotspot (old Tethering)
2. Turn ON iPhone's Bluetooth and perform the Bluetooth pairing with your Mac in the   usual way